# Find Missing Values by Index Without NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with 3 columns: `pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Name', 'Payment'])` where I have made Date the index.  If I have a list of all `Name` values that are possible, how can I find indexes (in this case Dates) that are missing names from the possible universe and list which names they are specifically missing?

To be clear, there are not `NaNs` or `Nulls` in Payment so I'm not able to utilize boolean indexing in this case (as far as I know).

```
poss_names=['James', 'Patrick']
```

Example data: `[['2010-01-01', 'Patrick', 20],['2010-01-02', 'James', 20]]`

Expected output would show `[['2010-01-01', 'James'], ['2010-01-02', 'Patrick']`

Comment: Please add some example data, and an expected output

Comment: @EmiOB Added, though I think completely unnecessary in this context

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve, hence the request for an example. I'm still confused on what you're actually trying to do though

Comment: I am trying to find what indexes do not have a row for every name.  In this case, which dates do not have an observation for each name possible.  So i'd like to know the following: 1) Which dates do not have every name possible 2) what names are missing from each date, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're trying to achieve. I've made a longer example which I think is better for comprehensive testing. I have not set the date as the index, as I will need to use it (I don't know if you have to do this for other reasons, but you can `reset_index` for this):

```
         Date     Name  Payment
0  2010-01-01  Patrick       20
1  2010-01-02    James       20
2  2010-01-02  Patrick       20
3  2010-01-03    James       20
4  2010-01-03  Patrick       20
5  2010-01-03      Joe       20

poss_names=['James', 'Patrick', 'Joe']
```

Firstly, I've used pandas `groupby()` to group the data by each Date, and used a function to put all the names for that date into a list as below:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Date').agg({'Name':lambda s: list(set(s))})

                             Name
Date                             
2010-01-01              [Patrick]
2010-01-02       [Patrick, James]
2010-01-03  [Patrick, Joe, James]
```

I've then used an apply function to get the rows of Name that contain all the possible names, and used `.loc[]` to filter these out:

```
df2 = df2.loc[~df2['Name'].apply(lambda x: set(poss_names) == set(x))]

                        Name
Date                        
2010-01-01         [Patrick]
2010-01-02  [Patrick, James]
```

Finally, I've used another apply function with list comprehension to go through the possible names and work out which are missing for each date:

```
df2 = df2['Name'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in poss_names if i not in x])

Date
2010-01-01    [James, Joe]
2010-01-02           [Joe]
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Full Code:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Date').agg({'Name':lambda s: list(set(s))})
df2 = df2.loc[~df2['Name'].apply(lambda x: set(poss_names) == set(x))]
df2 = df2['Name'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in poss_names if i not in x])
```